# Event reference is undefined on event listener callback passed as a method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, addeventlistener

Callback method is not being called when I attach my event to element. The method in question belongs to an object but it seems the way I am calling it the method isn't being called when the click event occurs.

```
 var myObject = {
     handledrop : function () {
          
         //retrieved created html element
         var elem = document.getElementById("required");
         elem.addEventListener("click", this.deleteFavorite.bind(this), false);
     },

     //this method isn't being called when click event occurs
     deleteFavorite: function (evt) {
        console.log(evt);
     }
 }
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I pass the right context so that the correct method is called and passed the right context which is event

Comment: seems to work just fine -> **https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/t4zoresh/**

Comment: `addEventListner` is spelled incorrectly. Does fixing it solve the problem?

Comment: @Traktor53 no that was just a misspelling here

Comment: Ok, call `myObject.handledrop()` after the window has loaded. As posted the listener registration has been coded as an object method but not called

Answer (score 1):

Couple of debug/trouble-shooting tips:

1. Post the html for the "required" element.
2. Check that the "required" element you think you're getting is valid:

   ```
   var elem = document.getElementById("required");
   console.log('elem:',elem);
   ```
3. You can also iterate its properties to ensure that function exists:

   ```
   foreach(var property in elem){
       console.log('property:',property);
   }
   ```

For cross browser support - you might want to read this post:
[addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)